# Upper bound for $|\delta|$ in $1+\delta=\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\varepsilon_i)^{\pm1}$

Tags: approximation

I am trying to prove the following lemma:

Let $|\varepsilon_i|\leq \varepsilon < \frac{1}{n} $ for all $1\leq i \leq n$ and define $\delta$ with

$$1+\delta=\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\varepsilon_i)^{\pm1}$$

then

$$|\delta| \leq \frac{n\varepsilon}{1-n\varepsilon}$$

The $\pm1$ in the exponent means that the exponent can be $1$ or $-1$ for any $i$ individually.

I am aware that this is a formula that allows approximations of the higher order terms of the product. As I understand it the product term has a leading $1$ and the rest are $\varepsilon_i$ dependant terms.

I have been looking through all my books searching for some useful product inequalities, however the exponent $\pm1$ and the sign of $\varepsilon_i$ rules most of them out, so I cannot use them. This inequality seemed the most promosing to deliver an upper bound:

- Let $a_i \in \mathbb{R_0^+}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \leq 1$, then
  $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i) \leq 1+2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i $$

However the nonfixed exponent bugs me and does not let me use it.

Are there any theorems or tricks I could use to get to my goal?

I am looking for hints, not for solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try taking log of both sides and using things like $\log(1+\epsilon) \leq \epsilon$...

Comment: Here are a couple things you could do depending on how tight a bound you'd like to have:
1) split the product into two products, one where all exponents are 1, the other with -1 as the exponent then apply product-sum inequalities to each.
2) consider the worst possible case using $\frac{1}{1-x} > 1+x$).

Comment: Using the worst case scenario I have found that $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\varepsilon_i)^{\pm1} \leq \prod_{i=1}^n (1-| \varepsilon_i |)^{-1}\leq \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\varepsilon)^{-1} = \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^n} \leq \frac{1}{1-n\varepsilon} < \frac{n\varepsilon}{1-n\varepsilon}$ using Bernoulli in the 2nd last inequaliy. How do I make a statement about$ |\delta| $now?

Comment: The last estimation of course is false, since $n\varepsilon<1$. Here's the correct finish: $\frac{1}{1-n \varepsilon}=\frac{1-n \varepsilon+n \varepsilon}{1-n \varepsilon}=1+\frac{n\varepsilon}{1-n \varepsilon}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final comments suggests that are already at the solution.

1. Define $\gamma_n = \frac{nu}{1-nu}$ for nonnegative $n$ such that $nu < 1$.
2. Show by direct calculation that $$\gamma_m + \gamma_n + \gamma_m
       \gamma_n \leq \gamma_{m+n}$$ for nonnegative $m$ and $n$ such that
   $(m+n)u < 1$.
3. Write $\langle m \rangle $ for any error term of the
   form $1 + \theta$, where $|\theta| \leq m$.
4. Realize that $$\langle m
   \rangle \langle n \rangle = \langle m + n \rangle$$ is just the
   previous inequality.
5. Note that $u \leq \gamma_1$.
6. Show $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} = \langle 1 \rangle$ for $|\epsilon| \leq u$.

This compact notation, i.e. $\langle m \rangle$ saves you the grief of inventing sensible names and it automatically keeps track of the size of the error terms.

Comment: I have made a mistake in my last inequality, I will correct it now. Thanks for your answer, I will take my time to understand the notation.